# Workbench and Salesforce

Tags: workbench

I cannot log into both **workbench and salesforce on chrome**.I am logged off from salesforce immediately as I log into workbench. Any one else facing the same issue?

Comment: So it works in other browsers?

Comment: I have experienced this same issue with other oAuth based tools recently.  Previously oAuth used to pick up on existing sessions but now it asks me to login a second time.

Comment: There are no known issues at this time, but it might have been related to this (Workbench is run on Heroku): https://status.heroku.com/incidents/554

Comment: Try changing the below option under login settings for workbench 

Pass Session to Salesforce

Answer (score 1):

I don't happen to see any issues on [trust.salesforce.com](http://trust.salesforce.com), and I can personally login on both. Something similar happened to me a few months ago, ***try clearing the cache and cookies on your browser***. That did it for me!

Answer (score -1):

sometimes clear cache in the browser solve session related issue